# Nil value for latitude when writing to local file

Tags: ios, swift

In a swift app, I need to write to a local file the latitude of the user.
Here is the function is use to write to a local file:

```
  func writeToFile(content: String) {

        let contentToAppend = content+"\n"


        //Check if file exists
        if let fileHandle = NSFileHandle(forWritingAtPath: filePathWrite) {
            //Append to file
            fileHandle.seekToEndOfFile()
            fileHandle.writeData(contentToAppend.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)
        }
        else {
            //Create new file
            do {
                try contentToAppend.writeToFile(filePathWrite, atomically: true, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
            } catch {
                print("Error creating \(filePathWrite)")
            }
        }
    }
```

I use it like this:

```
writeToFile(String(locations.last!.coordinate.latitude))
```

For the line above, I get this error: "unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

However, I tested the function with a random string ("hello" for example) and it works fine.
For the latitude, it also works fine since I get the updated latitude value on the screen when it changes.

I've added a condition to avoid nil values:

```
if locations.last!.coordinate.latitude != nil{
             writeToFile(String(locations.last!.coordinate.latitude))
            }
```

But now I get "CLLocationdegrees can never be nil, comparison nos allowed".

So it can't be nil, but I still get an error because it's nil.
What am I missing ?

Any input will be much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part causing the "unexpectedly found nil" is the force-unwrapping of `locations.last`. Avoid using `!` to force unwrap.

Your `if` statement should just check to see if `locations.last` is `nil`:

```
if locations.last != nil {
    writeToFile(String(locations.last!.coordinate.latitude))
}
```

But you should do this the "correct" way:

```
if let last = locations.last {
    writeToFile(String(last.coordinate.latitude))
}
```